# Calling random line from multiple text files

Tags: python, random

so lets say i have 5 text files a.txt, b.txt, c.txt, d.txt, e.txt. I want to be able to read the contents from each and call a random line from each one
a: rand from a.txt
b: rand from b.txt
etc

so far this works for one text file...

```
import random

contents=[]

with open("a.txt") as a:
    for line in a:
        line=line.strip()
        contents.append(line)

print "Welcome!"
print ""
print "a:", contents[random.randint(0,len(contents)-1)]
```

cheers for any help <3

Comment: A lists of lists, or a dictionary of lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use foo loop.

Use [randmo.choice](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random#random.choice) instead of [random.randint](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random#random.randint):

```
import os
import random

for filepath in ['a.txt', 'b.txt', 'c.txt', 'd.txt', 'e.txt']:
    with open(filepath) as f:
        lines = [line.strip() for line in f]
    print os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(filepath))[0], ':', random.choice(lines)
```

Comment: this is good, thank you for your help. one question... is it possible to print the filepath without .txt? use multiple print lines? im not sure.

Comment: @kyzer, I updated the code to print only filename without extension using `os.path.basename` + `os.path.splitext`.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your logic into a function that takes the file name as parameter, and at the same time put the random pick into that function:

```
import random

def pick_random(filename):
    contents=[]
    with open(filename) as a:
        for line in a:
            line=line.strip()
            contents.append(line)
    return contents[random.randint(0,len(contents)-1)]

print "Welcome!"
print ""
print "a:", pick_random("a.txt")
print "b:", pick_random("b.txt")
```

You can call the function for each file you want to pick a line from, either by calling them one by one like above, or putting all files into a list and looping over them.

This is a straightforward extension to your code, but consider falsetru's answer for a clearer solution. Using [random.choice](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random#random.choice) makes it more explicit what you want to accomplish.